# Batch - Copy specific text from one file to another

Tags: batch-file, text, cmd, copy

I need some help with the problem below, and being a batch noob I don't know how I can go about doing this:

I have two .txt files, the first one contains:

- 1207, nameofsomething1,   rubbish,
- 1208, nameofsomething2,   rubbish,
- 1209, nameofsomething3,   rubbish,

In the second txt file has the following:

- 16987, nameofsomething1, rubbish,
- 16988, nameofsomething2, rubbish,
- 16989, nameofsomething3, rubbish,

I want to make the batch file search through the names in the second column (nameofsomething1 & beyond) from the first txt file, copy the number before it and replace the numbers in the second .txt from the first for their corresponding names. Second txt file is all muddled up with more information which I don't want to touch, I just need to change the numbers. Thanks for the help

Comment: Do both files follow the same convention for all of their content - `number, name, rubbish,`?

Comment: Yes they do. Also second text has duplicates (there could be only one of nameofsomething1 and maybe 5 lines with nameofsomething3 in second text)

Comment: Will each duplicate of nameofsomething3 have the same number?

Comment: Yes all of nameofsomething3 in the second text will have the same number, but will be different from the number for nameofsomething3 in the first text file.

Comment: okay, will "rubbish" change, or is the number the only difference in the lines?

Comment: Or a better question might be, do you just want to replace the line in the second file with the line from the first - where the names match?

Comment: No, I just want to change the first number in the second text with the first number from the first text. Leave the rest untouched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
:: remove variables starting $
FOR  /F "delims==" %%a In ('set $ 2^>Nul') DO SET "%%a="
FOR /f "tokens=1,2delims=," %%a IN (q21478068.txt) DO SET "$%%a=%%b"
(
FOR /f "tokens=1,2*delims=," %%a IN (q214780682.txt) DO (
 SET "replaced="
 FOR  /F "tokens=1*delims=$=" %%r In ('set $') DO IF "%%b"=="%%s" SET replaced=Y&ECHO(%%r,%%b,%%c
 IF NOT DEFINED replaced ECHO(%%a,%%b,%%c
 )
)>newfile.txt
GOTO :EOF
```

`q21478068.txt` is your first file, `q214780682.txt` is your second. `newfile.txt` created.

Answer (score 0):

Test this on sample files: `file1.txt` and `file2.txt` and it rewrites `file2.txt`

`nameofsomething` is the term in your lines.

This uses a helper batch file called `repl.bat` - download from:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/qidqwztmetbvklt/repl.bat

Place `repl.bat` in the same folder as the batch file or in a folder that is on the path.

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=," %%a in ('find "nameofsomething" ^<"file1.txt" ') do (
   type "file2.txt" |repl "^.*(,%%b,.*)" "%%a$1" >file.tmp
   move file.tmp "file2.txt"
)
pause
```